# How do I choose between pickers

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use multiple pickers and I have the code worked out for one, but I do not know how to work with two. Based on some other answers that I have found I believe that I should use an if statement, but I am really new to Swift and I do not know how to make this work. The code below is everything I have.

```
import UIKit

class RankViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var typeField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateField : UITextField!
     
    let wineTypes = ["Red","White","Rose","Sparkling","Ice - Red","Ice - White", "Port","Fruit","Other"]
    
    let wineRate = ["Hurray", "Meh", "Boo"]
    
    var typeView = UIPickerView()
    var rateView = UIPickerView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            
        typeView.delegate = self
        typeView.dataSource = self
                
        rateView.delegate = self
        rateView.dataSource = self
        
        typeField.inputView = typeView
        rateField.inputView = rateView
    }
    
    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        
        if([pickerView isEqual: typeView]){
            return wineTypes.count
        }
        if([pickerView isEqual: rateView]){
            return wineRate.count
        }
    }
        
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return wineTypes[row]
        }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        typeField.text = wineTypes[row]
        typeField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

This is the if statement that is giving me the error.

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    
    if([pickerView isEqual: typeView]){
        return wineTypes.count
    }
    if([pickerView isEqual: rateView]){
        return wineRate.count
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: `if ([pickerView isEqual: typeView])` is Objective-C.  You want `if pickerView == typeView {`.

Comment: `switch pickerView { case typeView: return wineTypes.count; case rateView: return wineRate.count; default: fatalError() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put if statements inside the delegate & data source functions

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == typeView {
        // Returns for typeView
        return 1
    }
    else if pickerView == rateView {
        // Returns for rateView
        return 1
    }

    return 1
}
    
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == typeView {
        // Returns for typeView
        return wineTypes.count
    }
    else if pickerView == rateView {
        // Returns for rateView
        return wineRate.count
    }
    return wineRate.count
}
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == typeView {
        // Returns for typeView
        return wineTypes[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == rateView {
        // Returns for rateView
        return wineRate[row]
    }
        return wineRate[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == typeView {
        // Do stuff for typeView
        typeField.text = wineTypes[row]
        typeField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if pickerView == rateView {
        // Do stuff for rateView
        typeField.text = wineRate[row]
        typeField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[pickerView isEqual: rateView]` is an objective c statement

you have two option

first one:

```
if pickerView == typeView {...}
```

second one: adding a tag to your pickerView which is Unique integer number and then check by the tag

in ViewDidLoad:

```
typeView.tag = 100
```

how to use:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

if pickerView.tag == 100 {....} 

}
```